# creating a sql query in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql

I have a table user_likes with 2 fields size 200 varchar email,likedby_email

The query needs to find me all the matches a user have. A match is the situation that a user give a like and he received a like from the user he liked

when a user likes somebody i insert to the column likedby_email the user email that login and to the email column the email of the user that received the like

In the image - you can see the lina, nir have a match:

[image: 1]

I tried to create a select statement that
when a user login he can see all his massages.

Thanks for any help(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT t1.email, t2.email
FROM Table1 as t1, Table1 as t2
WHERE t1.email = t2.likedby_email AND t1.likedby_email = t2.email
  AND t1.email = 'Lina@gmail.com'` -- To filter out currently logged in user
```

Comment: you are a genius!